# Mocking calls to super class in python through

Tags: python, testing, mocking, tdd, patch

I am trying to mock the super class of a class with a setup similar to this:

File *parent.py*

```py
class Parent:
    def write(self):
        *some code*
```

File *child.py*

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def write(self):
        *more code*
        super().write()
```

File *mock_parent.py*

```py
class MockParent(Parent):
    def write(self):
        ...
```

My goal would be to replace `Parent` with `MockParent` to improve testing of `Child`, by eliminating real hardware resources.

So far I tried to use mock patch with no success. I tried to patch imports, **bases** and super but none of these attempts had been successful. I could replace the internals of the Child object, but I would prefer to have a cleaner solution through patching potentially.

The biggest challenge is that the call to the method `write` of the parent class (by `super().write()`) is inside the subclass method, otherwise I could simply assign it the function I want to be called.

Answer (score 0):

In this moment I have found this solution which needs a change to the code of the method `write` of the class `Child`. This modification must be used only during the test, while, in production code you have to used your production code.

Below I show you the file `test_code.py` which contains the production code and the test code:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock

class Parent:
    def write(self):
        print("parent.write()")

class Child(Parent):
    def write(self, *super_class):
        print("child.write()")
        # ----> Here I have changed your code
        if len(super_class) > 0:
            super_class[0].write()
        else:
            # ----> ... here you find your production code
            super().write()
class MockParent(Parent):
    def write(self):
        print("mock_parent.write()")

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_with_parent_mock(self):
        print("Execution of test_with_parent_mock")
        mock_parent = Mock(wraps = MockParent())
        child = Child()
        child.write(mock_parent)
        mock_parent.write.assert_called_once()

    def test_with_parent(self):
        print("Execution of test_with_parent")
        child = Child()
        child.write()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If you execute this code by the command `python test_code.py`, you will obtain the following output:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
Execution of test_with_parent
child.write()
parent.write()
Execution of test_with_parent_mock
child.write()
mock_parent.write()
```

The output of the test method `test_with_parent_mock()` shows that you can substitute the `write()` method of the super class with an other method defined in `MockParent`.

Instead in the method `test_with_parent()` you can call the `write()` method of the class Child normally.

### Note about TDD

What I have proposed to you is only a workaround, but I don't know if it is suited to reach your goal because I see that between the tags selected by you, there is TDD. However I hope this code could be useful.